# Plot several lines at once - Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, math, matplotlib, visualization

I have the following code I want to optimize:

```
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, radians, allclose
π = pi
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

def points_arround_circle(center=(0,0), radius=1, number=100):
    x = [special_round(radius * cos(θ)) for θ in increment_angle(number)]
    y = [special_round(radius * sin(θ)) for θ in increment_angle(number)]
    return (x, y)

def increment_angle(number):
    Δθ = 2 * π / number
    θ = 0
    while θ < 2 * π:
        yield θ
        θ += Δθ

def special_round(n):
    if allclose(n, 0):
        return 0
    return n

def get_lines_from_points(x, y,factor):
    limit = len(x)
    for i in range(limit):
        x_range = (x[int(i%limit)], x[int((i*factor)%limit)])
        y_range = (y[int(i%limit)], y[int((i*factor)%limit)])
        yield x_range, y_range

def plot_circle_points(x, y):
    plt.plot(x, y, "ro", ms=1)
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        plt.annotate(i, (x,y))

def plot_lines(factor, x, y):
    plt.annotate("Valor: {}".format(factor), (0.8, 0.9))
    for x, y in get_lines_from_points(x, y, factor):
        plt.plot(x, y, "k", linewidth=0.5)

def plot_static():
    x, y = points_arround_circle()
    plot_circle_points(x, y)
    plot_lines(2,x,y)

plot_static()
```

Profiling:

```
Line#     Hits        Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
36                                           def plot_static():
37         1        58941  58941.0      5.7      x, y = points_arround_circle()
38         1        71392  71392.0      6.9      plot_circle_points(x, y)
39         1       902380 902380.0     87.4      plot_lines(2,x,y)
```

My first approach was to utilize numpy to refactor the first 3 functions and the     result was this:

```
def points_arround_circle(center=(0,0), radius=1, number=100):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*π, number)
    x = radius * np.cos(theta)
    y = radius * np.sin(theta)
    return (x, y)

def get_lines_from_points(x, y,factor):
    limit = len(x)
    for i in range(limit):
        x_range = (x[int(i)], x[int((i*factor)%limit)])
        y_range = (y[int(i)], y[int((i*factor)%limit)])
        yield mlines.Line2D(x_range, y_range, color='black', linewidth=0.5)

def plot_circle_points(x, y, labels=None):
    plt.plot(x, y, "-ko", markevery=1)
    if not labels is None:
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
            plt.annotate(i, (x,y))

def plot_lines(factor, x, y):
    ax.annotate("Valor: {}".format(factor), (0.8, 0.9))
    for line in get_lines_from_points(x, y, factor):
        ax.add_line(line)

def plot_static():
    x, y = points_arround_circle()
    plot_circle_points(x, y)
    plot_lines(2,x,y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
ax.set_xlim([-1.1,1.1])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1,1.1])
plot_static()
```

After this refactoring the 98% of the time is consumed by the plot_lines function and if plot_circle_points' labels flag is not None, the time consumed by it increase a bit too.

My concerns/questions are:

- Which is the most pythonic way to write this program?
- Is it possible to achieve the same with less but still readable code?
- Is there a way to improve the performance of plot_lines?
- Is there a way to plot all the annotations at once? (Vectorize annotations)

The desired result is
[image: desired result]

This is the python implementation for the [Making TimesTables from Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhbuKbxJsk8)

Comment: The first two points are completely opinion based. For the third point you may consider using numpy and a LineCollection instead of individual Line2D objects. The answer to the forth point is essentially "no", but you have already found a workaround by looping over the points.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I didn't know about the existence of LineCollection, it worked!